# using Truecrypt-Folder/File in Dropbox/Cloud/ public storage

Tags: truecrypt

I appreciate any help with my questions: If I links (or copy) my OuterVolume (OV) or HiddenFile (HF) to Dropbox (where every1 can access it):

1- will only the OV (not HF) be visible to every1?, but only me can open the OV and HF with PW??

2- if I copy and paste a HF 10 times to other places (which are NOT the OV), will these  10 HF copies still work as a HF (saving our time to create a new one)?

Answer (score 1):

A "HiddenFile" is not terminology used with respect of Truecrypt, although "Hidden Volume" is, and I assume that this is what you mean when you say HiddenFile.   I'll call it HV for Hidden Volume.

So there are 3 distinct elements to the Truecrypt file that you need to understand in order to handle your question -

1. The container (which could be a file or disk partition), and which would appear as a single file or block device - and which holds all your truecrypt data.
2. Your OV is encrypted, and is held inside the container, and is secured using a password.
3. Your HV is encrypted and is held inside the container.  It uses a different password to your OV.

If you want to "safely" backup your Truecrypt setup, you need to upload the container - not the HV or OV.

If you back up your OV or HV you are sending unencrypted files to the cloud which can be read without a password - because in order to copy these you need to read them from the open container, thus they are transferred unencrypted.

So to specifically answer your questions -

1. The contents of the OV will be visible if you copy it, but not the HV.  It will not require a password because it will be open already because its not a container.
2. Same as for (1) above.   Its not a container.

Some things you did not ask, but which are relevant -
Start by reading [this](https://www.truecrypt71a.com/documentation/plausible-deniability/hidden-volume/) - it shows the layout of a truecrypt container, and explains how everything is laid out - note that the header for both volumes is at the beginning of the container, which should be enough to highlight you need to copy the whole thing or you can't decrypt any data.

If you make multiple copies of the container at the same point in time, it should still be secure.  If you have copies at different points in time, its still secure against most attackers, but it is theoretically possible that extremely knowledgeable attackers can look at the differences and may weaken the security.

Truecrypt was discontinued (at a guess because of pressure from a Three Letter Agency). It may or may not be cracked. The candle was picked up by Veracrypt.  You should seriously consider changing to Veracrypt.  Read the full thread [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/72249/is-there-a-reason-to-use-truecrypt-over-veracrypt#72635) to see why.  (The original answer to choose Truecrypt was answered in 2014 and is outdated as there have now been external audits of Veracrypt)

Comment: Hi Davidgo. Thank you a lot for making clear of the existence of the main "Container". 

The Button "Select File" (instead of "Select Container")" is confusing. Same confusing as the hope of creating a hidden Container, which TC indeed means a visible (principal) Volume/Container which contains the OV +HV >>> Is there any way to make the (principal) Container invisible via TC-PassWord? (I do not mean the usual windows 'hidden properties'). Thanks

Comment: Not sure I understand the question, but if I do get what you are asking - no, you can't hide the existence of the outer container. Indeed the whole idea of having an HV is that you put innocent content in the OV and it should not possible for an attacker to know you have a HV (although they can overwrite it by filling up the OV)